# XSL Creation for XML Parsing in .CSV File

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

Expected outcome of below mention XML file in .CSV file using XSL parsing

Sample XML File

```
 <SCHOLARSHIP>
    <SCHOLARSHIP_DTL>
    <SCHOLARSHIP_NAME>Sports SCHOLARSHIP</SCHOLARSHIP_NAME>
    <ISSUE_DATE>21/12/2019</ISSUE_DATE>
    <AMOUNT>40000</AMOUNT>
    <STUDENTS>
    <STUDENT>
    <STUDENT_NAME>Alex</STUDENT_NAME>
    <SCHOOL_NAME>Monten</SCHOOL_NAME>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
    <STUDENT_NAME>Lena</STUDENT_NAME>
    <SCHOOL_NAME>Convent</SCHOOL_NAME>
    </STUDENT>
    </STUDENTS>
    </SCHOLARSHIP_DTL>
 </SCHOLARSHIP>
```

Expected output in .csv using Xsl parsing with above sample data

```
 SCHOLARSHIP_NAME,ISSUE_DATE,AMOUNT,STUDENT_NAME,SCHOOL_NAME
 Sports SCHOLARSHIP,21/12/2019,40000,Alex,Monten
 Sports SCHOLARSHIP,21/12/2019,40000,Lena,Convent
```

With Below mention xsl not getting multiple students

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
     SCHOLARSHIP_NAME,ISSUE_DATE,AMOUNT,STUDENT_NAME,SCHOOL_NAME
    <xsl:for-each select="SCHOLARSHIP/SCHOLARSHIP_DTL"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(SCHOLARSHIP_NAME,',',ISSUE_DATE,',',AMOUNT,',',STUDENTS/STUDENT/STUDENT_NAME,',',STUDENTS/STUDENT/SCHOOL_NAME,'&#xA;')"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive approach without handling quoted strings would be the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    SCHOLARSHIP_NAME,ISSUE_DATE,AMOUNT,STUDENT_NAME,SCHOOL_NAME
    <xsl:for-each select="SCHOLARSHIP/SCHOLARSHIP_DTL"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="STUDENTS/STUDENT"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../SCHOLARSHIP_NAME,',',../../ISSUE_DATE,',',../../AMOUNT,',',STUDENT_NAME,',',SCHOOL_NAME,'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is:

```
SCHOLARSHIP_NAME,ISSUE_DATE,AMOUNT,STUDENT_NAME,SCHOOL_NAME
Sports SCHOLARSHIP,21/12/2019,40000,Alex,Monten
Sports SCHOLARSHIP,21/12/2019,40000,Lena,Convent
```

The preferred output method, specified as top-level element (child of `xsl:stylesheet`), should be "text" like this:

```
<xsl:output method="text" />
```